# Facebook Button not showing up

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've looked at the other post on here for issue's with Facebook like button not showing up and can't seem to figure out why in the world the Facebook like button I am trying to add is not showing up. I've followed the steps on the FB developer page but still not showing. Here is my code. Is there something wrong that I am not seeing or doing?

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=1402069220010998";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.winvipconcert.com"data-width="350" data-show-faces="false" data-send="false"></div>
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me tested on Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for your response Malcolm... for some reason on my end in chrome, safari, and FF it doesn't show up at all.

Comment: Works fine for me too on chrome and firefox

Comment: What happens when you enter your URL into the plugin on FB?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: Malcolm - Entered the url into the plugin on the fb link you provided and no errors. cant figure out why this thing isn't showing up?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache??

Comment: yeah cleared the cache and nothing... thanks for your responses... appreciate it!

Comment: Malcolm just checked chrome inspector and I've got a "failed to load resource file://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=1402069220010998 error but in firefox I have no errors in the console... go figure

Comment: I take it you are using the HTML5 version of the code? if using XFBML try adding <html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"> as your < HTML > opening tag, just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me on chrome and firefox. My guess is this is a styling issue. Check the styles of the container that wraps the `div.fb-like`

Comment: Agent47DarkSoul thanks for your response... I checked of the container that wraps the div.fb-like and the styles seem to be fine

Comment: Ok, after the page is loaded, can you check whether an iframe is created. Also check styles on the iframe.

Comment: I had somewhat similar issue with the like popup that comes after clicking on like button, it turned out to be `position` style problem.

Comment: I just checked chrome inspector and I've got a "failed to load resource file://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=1402069220010998 error but in firefox I have no errors in the console... go figure

Comment: so its not loading the javascript?

Comment: Are you directly running your html (as in double clicking it and opening in chrome)? If yes, that is the issue, because the script has a url with no protocol in it (required to allow http and https sites to work in a uniform way), and since you are directly running it, the browser is trying to load the facebook script from local file system.

Comment: yes... I am working in dreamweaver and previewing my code with "browser preview"(ff, chrome, safari).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, there is little difference between your code but see if it works.

```
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=1402069220010998";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Comment: Malcolm tried your code and I am getting a grey box with a sad face icon... Lol something is finally working now

Comment: Lol I don't think I have ever seen a grey box with a sad face icon on the like button :/